# ffprobe or avprobe not found. Please install one

Tags: youtube, ffmpeg, centos, ffprobe

I want to add tags to mp3 converted by youtube-dl & ffmpeg:

> youtube-dl -o
> '/Output/qpgTC9MDx1o.mp3' qpgTC9MDx1o -f bestaudio --extract-audio --metadata-from-title "%(artist)s -
> %(title)s" 2>&1

I have this error in the output result:

> [youtube] qpgTC9MDx1o: Downloading webpage [youtube] qpgTC9MDx1o:
> Extracting video information [youtube] qpgTC9MDx1o: Downloading js
> player en_US-vfluGO3jj [youtube] qpgTC9MDx1o: Downloading DASH
> manifest [download]
> /var/www/vhosts/mp3-y.com/httpdocs/Mp3_Output/quick-mp3.com-JALAL-EL-HAMDAOUI-2007-ARRASSIATES-VOL2-F1P-9CDoxlQ.mp3
> has already been downloaded [download] 100% of 13.43MiB WARNING:
> qpgTC9MDx1o: writing DASH m4a. Only some players support this
> container. Install ffmpeg or avconv to fix this automatically.
> [fromtitle] parsed artist: Maroon 5 [fromtitle] parsed title: Animals
> ERROR: ffprobe or avprobe not found. Please install one.

Comment: how i verify if ffprobe installed in centos ? and if not how i can make install ?

Comment: That's a rather different question, and one that is probably better asked on either [Unix.SE] or [SU], since I'm pretty sure ffprobe is not a programmer-exclusive tool.

Comment: Maybe ask the authors of youtube-dl or post on their GitHub project page?

Comment: I came here because I get the error when I download a video with `youtube-dl` and want to convert it to `mp3`: `options={..'preferredcodec': 'mp3'..}`

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest version for youtube-dl:
`sudo youtube-dl -U`

After that you can solve this problem by installing the missing `ffmpeg`.

Ubuntu and debian:
`sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

macOS:
`brew install ffmpeg`

Windows:
`choco install ffmpeg`

Comment: On MacOS you should use ```brew upgrade youtube-dl``` to make sure you have latest version of youtube-dl

Comment: On windows its choco install ffmpeg

Comment: I thought brew take care of dependencies itself. So why is ffmpeg not installed in the first place?

Comment: @jxhyc probably because ffmpeg isn't needed for youtube-dl basic use cases.  For example, only if you use the -x option to convert the video to audio, but not just to download the video with no -x flag.

Comment: `brew reinstall ffmpeg` works for me

Comment: [`youtube-dl`](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) is not updated anymore since last release december 2021.

Comment: `ffmpeg` is huge, is there another option if I want to convert from video to mp3?

Answer (score 102):

`brew install ffmpeg` will install what you need and all the dependencies if you are on a Mac.

Comment: windows alternative?

Comment: @3kstc see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77577950/4094231 for Windows solution.

Answer (score 85):

I know the user asked this for Linux, but I had this issue in Windows (10 64bits) and found little information, so this is how I solved it:

- Download [LIBAV](http://builds.libav.org/windows/release-gpl/), I used libav-11.3-win64.7z. Just copy "avprobe.exe" and all DLLs from "/win64/usr/bin" to where "youtube-dl.exe" is.

In case LIBAV does not help, try with [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), copying the contents of the "bin" folder to where "youtube-dl.exe" is. That did not help me, but others said it did, so it may worth a try.

Hope this helps someone having the issue in Windows.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me. A small correction to this. You should copy the contents of the bin folder to where youtube-dl.exe is.

Comment: I had success by just copying the extracted contents of LIBAV to the Program Files folder and added the path to "C:\Program Files\libav-11.3-win64\win64\usr\bin" as an environment variable to the System Path group.

Comment: This is what Windows users need to do. I went for the FFMPEG instructions, but the link is no longer working, so I [used this](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/) instead.

Comment: both URLs are dead

Comment: @FelixJassler did you try Google for new links??? The answer is 7 years old...

Comment: @FedericoAlvarez I wanted to edit your answer with updated links, but SO doesn't let me :/

Comment: Googling as @FelixJassler suggested yields https://ffmpeg.org/download.html . For windows https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-release-essentials.zip worked for me. Just moved files under `bin` directory --namely `ffmpeg.exe`, `ffplay.exe`, `ffprobe.exe`-- into `~/.bin` after creating the directory and adding to PATH of course.

Comment: I had the files of ffmpeg in a subfolder of the the one containing the youtube-dl.exe in windows. Moving the files from ffmpeg folder directly into the folder where youtube-dl.exe is, solved the problem for me (since there is no config, that would tell the .exe where to find the path to ffmpeg)

Answer (score 64):

On Windows, you can easily install ffmpeg via [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/ffmpeg)

> choco install ffmpeg

Comment: Why did you downvote this one? I have installed chocolatey then install ffmpeg with choco on Windows command window. After successfully installed ffmpeg - I am able to convert it to mp3

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks buddy. Choco has really made windows very developer friendly

Answer (score 36):

There is some confusion when using `pip install` in Windows. The instructions talk about a specific folder which has `youtube-dl.exe`. There is no such folder if you use `pip install`.

The solution is to:

- Download one of the builds from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/
- Extract the zip contents
- Place the contents of the `bin` folder (there are three exe files) in any folder which is a `path` in Windows. I personally use Ananconda, so I placed them in `/Anaconda/Scripts`, but you could place it in any folder and add that folder to the path.

Answer (score 33):

Compiling the last answers into one:

If you're on **Windows**, use [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/ffmpeg):

```
choco install ffmpeg
```

If you are on **Mac**, use Brew:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

If you are on a **Debian Linux** distribution, use apt:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

And make sure Youtube-dl is updated:

```
youtube-dl -U
```

Answer (score 23):

What worked for me (youtube-dl version 2018.03.03, ffprobe 0.5, no avprobe, 3.4.1-tessus, in Hi-Sierra/iMac) was:

> brew install libav

(thanks to marciovsena's [post on GitHub](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/3160)).

I saw elsewhere that libav might be deprecated in the future, but I'll worry about it when we get there.

Comment: That will install `avprobe` from the Libav fork. `brew install ffmpeg` should install `ffprobe` from FFmpeg. I guess either will work with `youtube-dl`, but FFmpeg is  much more active organization than Libav.

Answer (score 6):

You can install them by

```
sudo apt-get install -y libav-tools
```

Comment: If you're referring to Ubuntu, then as of 15.10 libav-tools is a virtual/transitional package and points to ffmpeg package, so there is no need to use it instead of ffmpeg.

Answer (score 6):

- Update your version of youtube-dl to the lastest as older version might not support.

  ```
   pip install --upgrade youtube_dl
  ```
- Install 'ffmpeg' and 'ffprobe' module

  ```
   pip install ffmpeg
   pip install ffprobe
  ```
- If you face the same issue, then download [ffmpeg builds](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) and put all the .exe files to Script folder($path: "Python\Python38-32\Scripts") (Windows OS only)

Comment: link is failing

Answer (score 2):

This is so simple if on windows...

In the folder where you have youtube-dl.exe

goto https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/

download the ffmpeg-git-full.7z file
the download link is https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-git-full.7z

Open that zip file and move the ffmpeg.exe file to the same folder where youtube-dl.exe is

Example "blahblah.7z / whatevertherootfolderis / bin / ffmpeg.exe"

youtube-dl.exe -x --audio-format mp3 -o %(title)s.%(ext)s https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyPKRcBTsFQ

Comment: I downloaded 64 bit version and my dinosaur PC couldn't handle it, hence after downloading 32 bit version, worked as a charm.

Comment: Well if you have a 32-bit (or x86) operating system, then it naturally it can't handle 64 bit software. It has nothing to do with it being a dinosaur, it's a compatibility issue.

Answer (score 1):

on **MAC** i tried to run `brew install ffmpeg` but it didn't work and got many errors, so i did this and it worked:

1- make sure you have the latest version of youtube-dl

```
pip install --upgrade youtube_dl
```

2- go to https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/ and download `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe`

3- run `which youtube-dl` on **Terminal** to get the path, where youtube-dl is installed.

you should get something like this : `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/`

4- copy the 2 file you downloaded `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` to the `bin` folder of your path from step 3.

that's it. you shouldn't get this error again.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, do this.

Go to https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases and download Windows file.

Extract to `C:\Program Files` and extract your zipped file.

Then go to `System Properties` and add `C:\Program Files\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl\bin` to `SYSTEM variables` `PATH`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, install `ffmpeg` by downloading it from:

https://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Under "Get packages & executable files/Static Builds for macOS 64-bit".

I downloaded `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe`.

After download, I extracted the binaries `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe`, copied them to my path and set permissions:

```
cp ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/
cp ffprobe /usr/local/bin/
chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/ff*
```

With `brew install ffmpeg` on macOS 10.13 I got the following `Error: ffmpeg: no bottle available!` and I was also not able to build ffmpeg on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Posting what i found recently, just so that it might be of help.

Once you have installed ffmpeg as stated by various answers here , use the below option to point to the location of ffmpeg .

in my case i've installed ffmpg in (on Windows PC)  E:\ffmpeg\bin

Use **underscore** rather than hyphen, while invoking youtube-dl from Python, and use **--ffmpeg-location** if calling from command line
eg

```
ydl_opts = {       
            'ffmpeg_location' : 'E:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe',
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps (for mac):

`rm -rf /usr/local/bin/yt-dlp*` or for youtube-dl: `rm -rf /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl*`

then run;

```
brew install yt-dlp
```

you'll get a symlink error which you can resolve by running:

```
brew link --overwrite yt-dlp
```

It should work now!!

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

1. update your version of youtube-dl to the lastest as older version might not support palylists.

   `sudo  youtube-dl -U if u installed via .deb`

   `sudo pip install --upgrade youtube_dl via pip`
2. use this to download the playlist as an **MP3** file

   `youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 #url_to_playlist`

Comment: this does not address the question .

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question. But if you're using a virtualenv with python, place the contents of the downloaded libav `bin` folder in the `Scripts`folder of your virtualenv.