# A music discord bot

Tags: python, discord

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
import ffmpeg
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.command()
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
    except PermissionError:
        await ctx.send("Wait for the current playing music to end or use the 'stop' command")
        return

    voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name='General')
    await voiceChannel.connect()
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))


@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_connected():
        await voice.disconnect()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The bot is not connected to a voice channel.")


@client.command()
async def pause(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_playing():
        voice.pause()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Currently no audio is playing.")


@client.command()
async def resume(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice.is_paused():
        voice.resume()
    else:
        await ctx.send("The audio is not paused.")


@client.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    voice.stop()


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Im getting an error can anyone help me with it? It was telling me that I have to install FFmpeg or FFrobe. raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: DownloadError: ERROR: ffprobe/avprobe and ffmpeg/avconv not found. Please install one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ffprobe or avprobe not found. Please install one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770155/ffprobe-or-avprobe-not-found-please-install-one)

Comment: NO but im still trying